How to copy class methods bound to an instance to a plain object in typescript?
I am writing a preload script for Electron and in the preload script we are importing a class, creating an instance and wanting to expose it in the render. Based on the Electron docs we cannot copy a class over the context bridge.
As a result, I created an object with keys that match the method names of the class, with values as class functions bound to an instance of the class like so:
// What I am given
class Calculator {
  add(a: number, b: number) { return a + b }
}

const instance = new Calculator();

// What I am trying to create programmatically
const calcObj = {
  add: Calculator.prototype.add.bind(instance)
}

The issue is the real classes I want to expose have many methods and there are many of the classes so I hope that I can create calcObj programmatically and keep the typescript types
While trying to do this programmatically this is the "best" thing I could come up with:
class Calculator {
  add(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }
  subtract(a: number, b: number) {
    return a - b;
  }
  multiply(a: number, b: number) {
    return a * b;
  }
  divide(a: number, b: number) {
    return a / b;
  }
  stringify() {
    return this.randomValue.toString();
  }

  randomValue = 0;
}

// Incorrect type, as it includes class variables (randomValue). Willing to live with this though
type ResultObject = {
  [K in keyof Calculator]: Calculator[K];
};

const instance = new Calculator();

// Maybe there is a better way to get class function names in a list?
const protoKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Calculator.prototype) as (keyof Calculator)[];

export const objCapture = protoKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  const fn = Calculator.prototype[key];
  if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
    return acc;
  }
  console.log('Copying function', key);
  // Typescript ERROR here, the result of fn.bind can be any 
  // of the function types on the class, which cannot be assigned to any of the acc[key]
  acc[key] = fn.bind(instance);
  return acc;
}, {} as ResultObject);

console.log(objCapture);

With this implementation I get a type error doing acc[key] = fn.bind(instance) where fn is Calculator.prototype[key] because it does not know which function fn is (can be any of add, stringify etc.) and it doesn't know which key of acc we are using. Additionally, my ResultObject technically isn't accurate either because it includes class variables (randomValue for example).
Is there a better way to create an object bound to a class instance like

"in the preload script we are importing a class, creating an instance and wanting to expose it in the render" - why so complicated? Wouldn't it be much easier to just load the script with the classes in the render?

The classes that we have are using node functionality so they can't be directly imported in the renderer and we have all of the recommended electron safety features enabled

• [key in in a mapped type is unconventional. What you're calling key is a generic type parameter. You should use K or maybe Key instead, or else it's distracting.  Please [edit] that. • Your ResultObject type is equivalent to Calculator, it's an identity mapped type. • You can suppress non-function valued props in that mapped type but it doesn't really distinguish between prototype vs instance properties, that's not something TS can do (see ms/TS#55904). (continued...)

(...continued)  • You might as well just assert to any as shown here if you're going to be munging things like this, the benefit of trying to convince TS you're doing something safe seems pretty low. • Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks, I think this does address my question. Essentially I gather that it is not possible for Typescript to understand that the new object has the same keys and uses the same type for each key as the original object. I also didn't know about reducing the ResultObject type as you did. I think the combination is a good answer and I will accept it.

I didn’t mean that it’s not possible, I just mean it’s not worth the effort.  I can probably do something with a generic callback that works that way mostly, but I don’t think it buys you much.  I’ll see if I can throw that together soon.

Yeah, it's really annoying to try. I keep hitting things like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54707 and working around it is so annoying for the minimal help it would buy you. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

TypeScript cannot distinguish at the type level whether or not a property is "own" or inherited. So when you look at Calculator.prototype, TypeScript just gives this the type Calculator, which isn't fully accurate because it includes instance properties like randomValue(). But whenever this is brought up (e.g., microsoft/TypeScript#55904) the TS team usually just says it is what it is, and it's probably not going to change.
If you assume that all non-function properties of a class instance belong to the instance directly, and that all function properties of a class are methods that belong to the prototype, then you can use key remapping to filter out all non-function properties to get an apporximation of the prototype type:
type ResultObject = {
  [K in keyof Calculator as Calculator[K] extends Function ? K : never]:
  Calculator[K];
};
/* type ResultObject = {
    add: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    subtract: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    multiply: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    divide: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    stringify: () => string;
} */


After this I think there's not much point in trying to convince TypeScript that what you're doing as safe.  You're already asserting that the initial {} object for reduce() is of type ResultObject, so you might as well just assert that fn.bind(instance) is some loose type like any and just move on:
const objCapture = protoKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  const fn = Calculator.prototype[key];
  if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
    return acc;
  }
  console.log('Copying function', key);
  acc[key] = fn.bind(instance) as any; // <-- might as well
  return acc;
}, {} as ResultObject);

You could try to write your reduce() callback in such a way that the compiler sees the relationship between acc[key] and fn.bind(instance), using the technique laid out in microsoft/TypeScript#47109 moving away from unions and toward generics, but it's tedious and complicated to explain:
type ResultMethod<K extends keyof ResultObject> =
    (...args: Parameters<ResultObject[K]>) => ReturnType<ResultObject[K]>

const objCapture = protoKeys.reduce(<K extends keyof ResultObject>(
    acc: { [P in K]: ResultMethod<P> }, key: K
) => {
    const proto: { [P in keyof ResultObject]: ResultMethod<P> } =
        Calculator.prototype;
    const fn: ResultMethod<K> = proto[key];
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        return acc;
    }
    acc[key] = fn.bind(instance);
    return acc;
}, {} as ResultObject);

That works, but why bother? It seems that unless your use case is quite atypical, the diminishing returns you get from having the compiler verify that fn.bind(instance) is compatible with acc[key] are just not worth the complexity.  I'm not inclined to spend several paragraphs explaining how it works here (you can read ms/TS#47109 for that) and I wouldn't expect anyone to maintain the above code instead of just using as any and being careful.
Playground link to code

Thanks @jcalz for the great answer and the links to the typescript project issues/discussions. Very insightful to how these work and the background
